# Link in an Editable NSTextView (like Apple's Notes)

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsattributedstring, nstextview

I have an `NSTextView` that is initially set as read-only like this:

```
taskDescription.isEditable = false
```

I set a click gesture recognizer in `viewDidLoad()` on it like this so that when the user clicks the field, it gets set as editable.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  let clickGesture = NSClickGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(setDescriptionEditState))
  clickGesture.numberOfClicksRequired = 1
  taskDescription.addGestureRecognizer(clickGesture)
}
```

And here is the function called on click:

```
@objc func setDescriptionEditState(){
  //Make it editable
  taskDescription.isEditable = true

  //Don't show automatic link detect while editing (I want plain text)
  taskDescription.checkTextInDocument(nil)

  //Put the cursor in the NSTextView  
  taskDescription.window?.makeFirstResponder(taskDescription)
}
```

Then when I load an `NSAttributedString` into it with a link in it, it shows up fine:

[image: NSTextView with a link]

Last of all, I implement this delegate method for `NSTextView`:

```
func textView(_ textView: NSTextView, clickedOnLink link: Any, at charIndex: Int) -> Bool {
  print(link) //<-- Never called
}
```

What's happening is the `clickGesture` is getting called instead of the link click. I know this because if I manually set the `NSTextView` to `isEditable = false` then the link works fine.

How can I allow the link click to happen while still allowing the user to click on the `NSTextView` to switch it into edit mode?

**--- Update ---**

I set the content of this `NSTextView` with an `NSAttributedString`. When logged to the console, it looks like this:

```
I want {
    NSColor = "...";
    NSFont = "...";
}a big link{
    NSColor = "...";
    NSFont = "...";
    NSLink = "google.com";
} here.{
    NSColor = "...";
    NSFont = "...";
}
```

So the link is specified with an `NSLink`.

Comment: For what it's worth, I have an identical setup in an iOS app, and the link tap is detected instead of making the `UITextView` editable.

Comment: Why is the text view ineditable if a click makes it editable?

Comment: @Willeke Because the link click doesn't work while it's editable (as far as I can tell).

Comment: Is the link a detected link or an attachment? Detected links do work in TextEdit.

Comment: @Willeke See my update in my question above. I use an `NSLink` in an `NSAttributedString`.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to override the function "touchesBegan" and implement your own logic.

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first
    guard let location = touch?.location(in: self.view) else { return }
    if !popupContainer.frame.contains(location) {
        goodTouch = true
    } else {
        goodTouch = false
    }
}
```

The variable "goodTouch" is established as a class property.  You can then check the status of this variable at the beginning of the functions in question and then route your application appropriately from there.  (This was specifically adapted from an iOS project I wrote, but should be the same for Cocoa).  Make sure if you implement this, you reset the "goodTouch" variable to false after inspecting it to be ready for the next round of touches.

**EDIT**
I think this is a more appropriate response to your specific example, but I didn't want to delete the code from above:

```
override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
    let textField = NSTextField() //this is for demo only...reference your actual object

    let location = event.locationInWindow
    let cgPoint = CGPoint(x: location.x, y: location.y)
    if textField.bounds.contains(cgPoint) {
        //fire the link here, over ride the click gesture recognizer
    } else {
        //change the editable style of the text field
    }
}
```

Comment: So you're saying I would override something like `mouseDown` and determine if the click happened on the link vs. anywhere else in the `NSTextView`? I'm unclear on how I would map the `NSEvent` location to the link's location.

Comment: I edited the above to answer that question.  The only code missing would be to include the super.mouseDown(event: event) to call the follow on code.